# EF Core Uses DBSet property name... sometimes

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a very simple `DataContex` set up with only a few sets.

```
public class ClaimContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ClaimContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public DbSet<Claim> Claims { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClaimType> ClaimTypes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<PropertyLoss> PropertyLosses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LiabilityLoss> LiabilityLosses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("default"));
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with EF Core's convention here. Sometimes as with the `Claims` property EF gets it right and looks for the `Claim` view. But with the `PropertyLosses` property EF tries to find a `PropertyLosses` object which doesn't exist. Instead, it is a `PropertyLoss` view.

I know that there is a way to be explicit with table names by applying a `Table("PropertyLoss")` attribute to my `PropertyLoss` entity, but I want to understand this inconsistent behavior. I prefer convention over configuration. So why does EF sometimes use the name of the `DBSet` property and sometimes use the name of the entity? What is going on here?

**Correction:**

Turns out that I was using a `TableAttribute` on my `Claim` table without realizing it. So I guess the answer to my own question is that EF core uses the name of the `DBSet`s and not the entities to identify tables. My organization names entities and tables with a single name like `Claim` or `Loss`. Does this mean that I have to always use the `TableAttribute`?

Comment: EF Core does not know English. It simply removes the `s` from the name. When it should remove `es` it gets confused. I think the only way is to set the table name.

Comment: For me, it doesn't have to do anything. The name is the name of the table. I am literally doing this:  `[Table(nameof(Claim))]` If I don't, it tries to access an object named Claims. It is adding an `s` in my case.

Comment: You can simply rename the properties, so `PropertyLosses` becomes `PropertyLoss`.

Comment: I know. That's suboptimal. I would actually prefer to use `TitleAttribute`. Than do that. But that's a good idea.